# Use ajax to retrieve data from Oracle database

Tags: ajax

I am completely new to AJAX. I have an HTML page where I need to fetch some data from the server. I followed a few tutorials from w3schools then I set foot on AJAX.

This is my strategy. I have one plain HTML file as `ajax.html` and a `jsp` file as `ajaxdb.jsp`. When a button is pressed I call a function `updateList()`.

This is my code:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(passParameter);

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
       document.getElementById("printBack").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
```

I have made the visibility of `printBack` div hidden so whatever goes in there is invisible. In the jsp page I have a table which contains all the list of employees. After this I use `dataTable.rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML = tempTable.rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML;` Where `tempTable` is a reference to the hidden table.

I think this is not the optimal solution for retrieving table content in AJAX please suggest me how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´d recommend to use jQuery´s AJAX functionality to achieve this:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Also from the JSP you should output the list of employees in a valid format (i.e.: JSON/XML).
Then show this list on your ajax.html page by using the complete function which will trigger when the request finishes. (make sure you check that status sent was "success").

There are several libraries available to help you convert an java array/object into JSON/XML format.

*EDIT* 
You can for example use http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/
Then just put the data you need in your JSONobject, and output it. From example:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject"%>
<%
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
obj.put("name","foo");
obj.put("num",new Integer(100));
obj.put("balance",new Double(1000.21));
obj.put("is_vip",new Boolean(true));
obj.put("nickname",null);
out.print(obj);
out.flush();
%>
```

Comment: Which is better to use? I think JSON is better than XML. I have no idea which one I should choose. The XML file which will be generated is that file will be saved in the server? If I change my data in the database will the XML updated?

Comment: I prefer to work with JSON. In my opinion it's also simpler to use than XML. You will not save the XML/JSON generated file - you will just output it through your JSP. I updated my answer with a reccomendation to a JSON library.

Comment: I have included `json-java.jar` file into my build path still I am getting error message as JSONObject is not defined. I don't get any syntactical error but when my page loads it gives this error. I am not able to solve.

Comment: Did you uncomment the //import org.json.simple.JSONObject line? *I updated my answer with example code from json-simple for adding a json object in a JSP file.

Comment: I have downloaded wrong file. I have downloaded the java.json library.. Now working fine. Thank you.